# OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом при db.session.add(aer) Python Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Пишу на  Python Flask SQLAlchemy

Запускаю программу, хочу добавить aer в бд но он лишь выводит мне мой except.

Говорю сразу бд создана через create_all из терминала, она существует в моей папке instance.
Пытался менять без ссылки на html файл, просто через ='Название', выводилась та же ошибка

*main.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from waitress import serve

# ссылка на сайт http://localhost:8080/


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///aeroports.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    raic = db.Column(db.String(8), unique=True)
    coordinate_x = db.Column(db.String(120))
    coordinate_y = db.Column(db.String(120))
    # ещё какие-то данные нужны?


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', api_key='33fbe2d1-b0dc-4315-bbf5-cc57da1dbe8f')


@app.route('/create', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        raic = request.form['raic']

        aer = Item(name=name, raic=raic )

        try:
            db.session.add(aer)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "При добавлении произошла ошибка"
    else:
        return render_template('create.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

*Ошибка*

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2023 05:56:11] "POST /create HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception in thread Thread-1 (serve_forever):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\PycharmProjects\ЛетняяПрактика\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 804, in serve_forever
    super().serve_forever(poll_interval=poll_interval)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 233, in serve_forever
    ready = selector.select(poll_interval)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом

Process finished with exit code -1
```

*create.html*

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Добавление записи </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Добавить запись</h1>
    <form method="post" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите название аэропорта" class="form-control"><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="raic" placeholder="Введите названия рейса аэропорта"><br>
        <button class="btn success" type="submit"> Добавить </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Структура]